# Is there a better way to show and hide multiple textviews linked to segmented control than isHidden = true/false?

Tags: ios, swift

Beginner here and I've created a VC with 3 segmented controls with 3 segments each. Each segment selection shows a different textview. At any given time, 2 segmented controls show and so you have the option to switch between any of 6 textviews. There exist a total of 9 textviews.

The way I've written this now seems a little glitchy in the simulator and so I want to know of a better way to write this kind of repetitive code. I many lines of .isHidden = false and isHidden = true between all of selections of the 2/3 segmented controls that show at any time. Can anyone tell me how something like can be written in a safer way? If you want to just give a short example or tell me what to google, I appreciate that.

Here's what I have:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var segmentedControl: UISegmentedControl!
    @IBOutlet weak var textSegmentedControl: UISegmentedControl!
    @IBOutlet weak var translationSegmentedControl: UISegmentedControl!
    @IBOutlet weak var firstLangText: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet weak var secondLangText: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet weak var thirdLangText: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet weak var translationA: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet weak var translationB: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet weak var translationC: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet weak var textInfo: UITextView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        style(control: segmentedControl)

        segmentedControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(updateMainSegmentedControl), for: .valueChanged)
        textSegmentedControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(updateTextSegmentedControl), for: .valueChanged)
        translationSegmentedControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(updateTranslationSegmentedControl), for: .valueChanged)

        secondLangText.isHidden = true
        thirdLangText.isHidden = true
        translationSegmentedControl.isHidden = true
        translationA.isHidden = true
        translationB.isHidden = true
        translationC.isHidden = true
}

    //Mark: Stye SegmentControls & underlineBar
    func style(control: UISegmentedControl) {
        control.backgroundColor = .clear
        control.tintColor = .clear
        control.setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.font : UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16), NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.secondaryColor], for: .normal)
        control.setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.font : UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16),NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.primaryColor], for: .selected)
    }

    @IBAction func textOrTranslationChange(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
        switch segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex {
        case 0:
            textSegmentedControl.isHidden = false
            translationSegmentedControl.isHidden = true
            translationUnderlineBar.isHidden = true
            firstLangText.isHidden = false
            translationA.isHidden = true
            textInfo.isHidden = true
        case 1:
            textSegmentedControl.isHidden = true
            translationSegmentedControl.isHidden = false
            firstLangText.isHidden = true
            translationA.isHidden = false
            textInfo.isHidden = true
        case 2:
            textSegmentedControl.isHidden = true
            translationSegmentedControl.isHidden = true
            firstLangText.isHidden = true
            textInfo.isHidden = false
        default:
            break;
        }
    }

    @IBAction func selectTextLanguage(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
        switch textSegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex {
        case 0:
            firstLangText.isHidden = false
            secondLangText.isHidden = true
            thirdLangText.isHidden = true
            translationA.isHidden = true
            translationB.isHidden = true
            translationC.isHidden = true
        case 1:
            firstLangText.isHidden = true
            secondLangText.isHidden = false
            thirdLangText.isHidden = true
            translationA.isHidden = true
            translationB.isHidden = true
            translationC.isHidden = true
        case 2:
            firstLangText.isHidden = true
            secondLangText.isHidden = true
            thirdLangText.isHidden = false
            translationA.isHidden = true
            translationB.isHidden = true
            translationC.isHidden = true
        default:
            break;
        }
    }

    @IBAction func selectTranslationLanguage(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
        switch translationSegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex {
        case 0:
            translationA.isHidden = false
            translationB.isHidden = true
            translationC.isHidden = true
            firstLangText.isHidden = true
            secondLangText.isHidden = true
            thirdLangText.isHidden = true
        case 1:
            translationA.isHidden = true
            translationB.isHidden = false
            translationC.isHidden = true
            firstLangText.isHidden = true
            secondLangText.isHidden = true
            thirdLangText.isHidden = true
        case 2:
            translationA.isHidden = true
            translationB.isHidden = true
            translationC.isHidden = false
            firstLangText.isHidden = true
            secondLangText.isHidden = true
            thirdLangText.isHidden = true
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

First you need to extract the behavior which is common from the switch case so that  you can remove some duplicate.

```
   @IBAction func textOrTranslationChange(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
        switch segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex {
        case 0:
            translationUnderlineBar.isHidden = true
            textInfo.isHidden = true
            firstLangText.isHidden = false
            translationA.isHidden = true
            textSegmentedControl.isHidden = false
            translationSegmentedControl.isHidden = true
        case 1:
            textInfo.isHidden = true
            firstLangText.isHidden = true
            translationA.isHidden = false
            textSegmentedControl.isHidden = true
            translationSegmentedControl.isHidden = false
        case 2:
            textInfo.isHidden = false
            firstLangText.isHidden = true
            textSegmentedControl.isHidden = true
            translationSegmentedControl.isHidden = true
        default:
            break;
        }
    }

    @IBAction func selectTextLanguage(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
        switch textSegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex {
        case 0:
            showLanaguage(which: firstLangText)
        case 1:
            showLanaguage(which: secondLangText)
        case 2:
            showLanaguage(which: thirdLangText)
        default:
            break;
        }
        translationA.isHidden = true
        translationB.isHidden = true
        translationC.isHidden = true
    }

    func showLanaguage(which: UITextView){
        [firstLangText,secondLangText,thirdLangText].forEach({
            $0?.isHidden = $0 != which
        })
    }

    func showTranslation(which: UITextView){
        [translationA,translationB,translationC].forEach({
            $0?.isHidden = $0 != which
        })
    }

    @IBAction func selectTranslationLanguage(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
        switch translationSegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex {
        case 0:
            showTranslation(which: translationA)
        case 1:
            showTranslation(which: translationB)
        case 2:
            showTranslation(which: translationC)
        default:
            break;
        }
        firstLangText.isHidden = true
        secondLangText.isHidden = true
        thirdLangText.isHidden = true
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could set them all to a default value before the switch and then just update the different ones in the case. This works especially well in your third method where the default state is true for most views.

```
@IBAction func selectTranslationLanguage(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) 
{
    [translationA, translationB, translationC, firstLangText,
     secondLangText, thirdLangText].forEach { $0.isHidden = true }

    switch translationSegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex 
    {
        case 0: translationA.isHidden = false
        case 1: translationB.isHidden = false
        case 2: translationC.isHidden = false
        default: break
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can reuse your text views if they have the same position. If they are meant to be different, you can group them using outlet collections. So you will have

```
@IBOutlet weak var langTextViews: [UITextView]!
```

Instead of:

```
@IBOutlet weak var firstLangText: UITextView!
@IBOutlet weak var secondLangText: UITextView!
@IBOutlet weak var thirdLangText: UITextView!
```

It will make your code more organized and readable. You can optimize the textView hiding/showing part. For example, `textOrTranslationChange` mehtod will look something like this:

```
@IBAction func textOrTranslationChange(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
  textSegmentedControl.isHidden = (segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex != 0)
  langTextViews[0].isHidden = (segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex != 0)
  translationSegmentedControl.isHidden = (segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex != 1)
  textInfo.isHidden = (segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex != 2)
  etc...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An elegant solution is to use the beauty of `UISegmentedControl`. Swift Dictionaries and the tag property.

**You can utilize a single `UITextView`** by setting the initial `tag` of the segmented control and then referencing the `tag` and `selectedIndex` to determine which field or value to change. You can then easily store the values in a `Dictionary` without the need of complex `switch` statements.

Here is a minimal, repeatable example. you should implement your own methods of handling values after input such as validation.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {
    // Properties

    var activeSegment: UISegmentedControl?
    var activeIndex: Int?

    var values:[String: String] = [:]


    lazy var segmentedController: UISegmentedControl = {
        let seg = UISegmentedControl(items: ["Name", "Age", "Language"])
        seg.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        seg.tag = 0
        seg.addTarget(self, action: #selector(segmentedControllerValueChanged(sender:)), for: .valueChanged)
        return seg
    }()

    lazy var secondSegmentedController: UISegmentedControl = {
        let seg = UISegmentedControl(items: ["Type", "Kind", "Thing"])
        seg.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        seg.tag = 1
        seg.addTarget(self, action: #selector(segmentedControllerValueChanged(sender:)), for: .valueChanged)
        return seg
    }()

    let textField: UITextField = {
        let tf = UITextField(frame: CGRect.zero)
        tf.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        tf.placeholder = "Select Field"
        return tf
    }()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        textField.delegate = self
        self.layoutSubviews()

    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    }

    func layoutSubviews() {
        let guide = self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        let spacing:CGFloat = 12.0

        self.view.addSubview(segmentedController)
        self.view.addSubview(secondSegmentedController)
        self.view.addSubview(textField)

        segmentedController.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: guide.widthAnchor).isActive = true
        segmentedController.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 55.0).isActive = true
        segmentedController.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: guide.bottomAnchor, constant: -spacing).isActive = true
        segmentedController.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: guide.centerXAnchor).isActive = true

        secondSegmentedController.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: guide.widthAnchor).isActive = true
        secondSegmentedController.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 55.0).isActive = true
        secondSegmentedController.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: segmentedController.topAnchor, constant: -spacing).isActive = true
        secondSegmentedController.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: guide.centerXAnchor).isActive = true

        textField.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: guide.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        textField.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: guide.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        textField.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 55.0).isActive = true
        textField.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: guide.widthAnchor, constant: -spacing*2).isActive = true

    }

    @objc func segmentedControllerValueChanged(sender: UISegmentedControl) {
        // Clear all other segments
        let segmentedcontrols = [segmentedController, secondSegmentedController]
        segmentedcontrols.forEach { (control) in
            if (control.tag != sender.tag) {
                control.selectedSegmentIndex = -1
            }
        }
        // Safely get the title for the index
        guard  let titleForIndex = sender.titleForSegment(at: sender.selectedSegmentIndex) else {
            self.textField.placeholder = "Select Field"
            return
        }

        // Set the active fields.
        self.textField.text = nil
        self.textField.placeholder = "Input " + titleForIndex
        self.activeSegment = sender
        self.activeIndex = sender.selectedSegmentIndex

        // Handle Text Input with your own methods / switch statements


        print("Value did change to: \( sender.selectedSegmentIndex) with tag \(sender.tag)" )
        print("values: \(values)")

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    //MARK: - Text Field Delegate

    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        // Safely get the title for the index

        guard let segment = activeSegment, let index = activeIndex, let activeSegmentTitle = segment.titleForSegment(at: index) else {
            return false
        }

        guard let text = textField.text else {
            return false
        }

        values[activeSegmentTitle] = text

        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        return true
    }
}
```

[image: View and Output Diagram]